# Getting an android view button's width after setting it programatically

Tags: android, view

During my oncreate I have a button that is drawn. I come back and have it resized as part of the viewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() method.  This works great.     Within the same onGlobalLayouyListener method how can I come back and retrieve the width and height of the button.  If I use btn.getwidth it returns the setting i have in my xml and not the value I just set. How can I retrieve the new width and height of the button.

```
 mainlayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        Cyclebuttons(mainlayout);
                        getwidth();}
 public void Cyclebuttons(ViewGroup parent) {
        int btn2height= somenumber;
        // set button width and height
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) btnx21.getLayoutParams();
        newLayoutParams.width = btn2height;
        newLayoutParams.height = btn2height;
        btnx21.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);
}
public Void getwidth{
btnx21.getwidth();
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't run the code, but the following might work:

```
public Void getwidth{
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) btnx21.getLayoutParams();
    return newLayoutParams.width;
}
```